# TypeOfErrore:AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'Extract'

Tags: python-3.7, linear-programming, or-tools

I'm using GLOP Linear Programming Solver from Ortools in Python. I have to define this type of constraint:

```
solver.Add(a_min*D_th_h[i]<=Pth_A1_K[i]+Pth_A2_K[i]+Pth_B[i]<=a_max*D_th_h[i] for i in range(0, T_tot))
```

but I get this error

```
return constraint.Extract(self, name)

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'Extract'
```

Could anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, can you please post more of your code? no one will be able to determine what type of object constraint is

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant this?

```py
for i in range(0, T_tot):
    solver.Add(a_min*D_th_h[i]<=Pth_A1_K[i]+Pth_A2_K[i]+Pth_B[i]<=a_max*D_th_h[i])
```

Comment: Thank you! In this way it works! But if I apply it in another case it doesn't work. I've tried to use it in this way:

`def th_from_el_production(P_el):
    return [mu_tilde*p+nu_tilde for p in P_el]

Pel_A1=[solver.NumVar(Pel_min*csi_K[i], Pel_max*csi_K[i], 'Pel_A1[%i]' %i) for i in range(0,T_tot)]
Pth_A1=[solver.NumVar(0, solver.infinity(), 'Pth_A1_K[%i]' %i) for i in range(0,T_tot)]

for i in range(0,T_tot):
  solver.Add(Pth_A1[i]==th_from_el_production(Pel_A1[i]) ) `

I got this error: TypeError: 'Variable' object is not iterable 
and I can't understand why

Comment: What is `th_from_el_production` supposed to do? It iterates over something but you are passing the `Pel_A1[i]` var?

Comment: I've modified `th_from_el_production` in `def th_from_el_production(P_el,csi):  for i in csi:   return [mu_tilde*p+nu_tilde*i for p in P_el] ` I would like that this method returns an array of the same length of `csi` and `P_el` and its values are a combination of the corresponding values in P_el and csi.. that is: `Pth_A1[0]=mu_tilde*Pel_A1[0]+nu_tilde*csi[0] `and so on.. I hope I was clear